# Best way to turn word list into frequency dict

Tags: python

What's the best way to convert a list/tuple into a dict where the keys are the distinct values of the list and the values are the the frequencies of those distinct values?

In other words:

```
['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c']
--> 
{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 1}
```

(I've had to do something like the above so many times, is there anything in the standard lib that does it for you?)

EDIT:

Jacob Gabrielson points out there is [something coming in the standard lib](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/collections.py?view=markup&pathrev=68559#Counter) for the 2.7/3.1 branch

Comment: Maybe define what you mean by best? Most efficient? Least amount of code? Easiest to understand?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Kind of

```
from collections import defaultdict
fq= defaultdict( int )
for w in words:
    fq[w] += 1
```

That usually works nicely.

Answer (score 43):

I find that the easiest to understand (while might not be the most efficient) way is to do:

```
{i:words.count(i) for i in set(words)}
```

Comment: reason why I love Python!

Comment: @S.Lott : dict comprehensions were introduced in 2.7, not 3.0 .

Comment: very elegant... but in worst (but real-life) cases, near quadratic cost. should be used with care.

Answer (score 17):

Just a note that, starting with Python 2.7/3.1, this functionality will be built in to the `collections` module, see [this bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1696199) for more information.  Here's the example from the [release notes](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c=Counter()
>>> for letter in 'here is a sample of english text':
...   c[letter] += 1
...
>>> c
Counter({' ': 6, 'e': 5, 's': 3, 'a': 2, 'i': 2, 'h': 2,
'l': 2, 't': 2, 'g': 1, 'f': 1, 'm': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1,
'p': 1, 'r': 1, 'x': 1})
>>> c['e']
5
>>> c['z']
0
```

Comment: looks even simpler than that, looks like you can just pass the string to the Counter constructor and it does it for you

Comment: You could simply do `Counter(word_list)`.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, the answer of Counter was already mentioned, but we can even do better (easier)!

```py
from collections import Counter
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c']
Counter(my_list)  # returns a Counter, dict-like object
>> Counter({'b': 3, 'a': 2, 'c': 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an abomination, but:

```
from itertools import groupby
dict((k, len(list(xs))) for k, xs in groupby(sorted(items)))
```

I can't think of a reason one would choose this method over S.Lott's, but if someone's going to point it out, it might as well be me. :)

Comment: I have to say that I just say this and tested it for performance (I'm looking at counting lists with literally millions of objects) and figured this had to be faster than repeatedly getting/setting hash-maps... But as it turns out this takes 4x as much CPU time for my tests when it has to sort the list, or 2x when the list is already sorted. Interesting. It is very clever though.

Comment: If you're handling millions of objects, you're better off using an external sort anyway (or offloading the sort to the data engine where your input is coming from, if possible). The `sort words.txt | uniq -c` chestnut in shell is hard to beat.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to go ahead and test the versions suggested, I found the `collections.Counter` as suggested by Jacob Gabrielson to be the fastest, followed by the `defaultdict` version by SLott.

Here are my codes :

```
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter

import random

# using default dict
def counter_default_dict(list):
    count=defaultdict(int)
    for i in list:
        count[i]+=1
    return count

# using normal dict
def counter_dict(list):
    count={}
    for i in list:
        count.update({i:count.get(i,0)+1})
    return count

# using count and dict
def counter_count(list):
    count={i:list.count(i) for i in set(list)}
    return count

# using count and dict
def counter_counter(list):
    count = Counter(list)
    return count

list=sorted([random.randint(0,250) for i in range(300)])


if __name__=='__main__':
    from timeit import timeit
    print("collections.Defaultdict ",timeit("counter_default_dict(list)", setup="from __main__ import counter_default_dict,list", number=1000))
    print("Dict",timeit("counter_dict(list)",setup="from __main__ import counter_dict,list",number=1000))
    print("list.count ",timeit("counter_count(list)", setup="from __main__ import counter_count,list", number=1000))
    print("collections.Counter.count ",timeit("counter_counter(list)", setup="from __main__ import counter_counter,list", number=1000))
```

And my results:

```
collections.Defaultdict 
0.06787874956330614
Dict
 0.15979115872995675
list.count 
 1.199258431219126
collections.Counter.count
 0.025896202538920665
```

Do let me know how I can improve the analysis.

Answer (score 2):

I think using collection library is the easiest way to get it. But If you want to get the frequency dictionary without using it then it's another way,

```
l = [1,4,2,1,2,6,8,2,2]
d ={}
for i in l:
    if i in d.keys():
        d[i] = 1 + d[i]
    else:
        d[i] = 1
print (d)
```

op:

```
{1: 2, 4: 1, 2: 4, 6: 1, 8: 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to share an interesting but kind of ridiculous way of doing it that I just came up with:

```
>>> class myfreq(dict):
...     def __init__(self, arr):
...         for k in arr:
...             self[k] = 1
...     def __setitem__(self, k, v):
...         dict.__setitem__(self, k, self.get(k, 0) + v)
... 
>>> myfreq(['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
{'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 3}
```

Comment: (self.get(k) or 0) can be better written as self.get(k, 0)